# MoveFileEx with MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING flag Fails with LastError = 183

Tags: visual-c++, movefileex

We have an application that makes a backup of a configuration file by copying it to a sub-folder (see log file entry below) using the following command:-

```
BOOL b = MoveFileEx(ExistingFileSpec, NewFileSpec, MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING | MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH | MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED);
```

This appears to work as expected on most systems but on two we get the following warning in our log file:-

> 11 Jun 2018  10:58:05.437 W.     COMMON      WARNING     MoveFile failed on C:\Program Files\Configuration\Stores.xml to C:\Program Files\Configuration\Backup\Stores.xml LastError=183

`Lasterror =183` means "`ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`"

This is odd since `MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING` is specifically meant to enable this command to work when the target file exists.

This is happening on `Win7 x86` machines.

In a previous version of the code `MoveFile` was used but with a `DeleteFile` call immediately prior to ensure the target file did not exist. When the code was rolled back to this version it works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently it was unable to replace the existing file for otherwise obscure reasons.  The top of the hit parade of wonky file system problems is firmly held by anti-malware.  They do treat XML files like dirt due to the DTD injection vulnerability.

Comment: Apologies I thought I had responded, myst have been distracted before adding comment. I have confirmed that one site is running Symantec but the other is not. The issue is not consistent at first site - some machines experience the problem, others do not. At the second site we have setup a test having changed to use ReplaceFile instead of MoveFile.